# Adb Connect to a Genymotion emulator running on a device in a Local Area Network

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, adb, virtualbox, emulation

I have a genymotion android emulator running on a device.

Now i want to connect to that emulator using ADB.

I tried to connect to that emulator runnong on another device with adb connct :5555.

It didnt worked!
both system are on same network

Comment: What did you try and what's the problem?

Comment: You can try to manually forward the adb TCP port of the emulator to the target device (e.g. using ssh port forwarding). The used port can be seen when executing `adb devices` on the system where the emulator is installed. If you want to try adb remote connection make sure not to use the adb version that is installed with Genymotion (usually this one is outdated). Install adb from latest Android SDK and configure Genymotion to use it: https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/02_Application/#use-third-party-adbsdk